# Is QML TableModel supported in PySide2?

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside2

I've been getting up to speed with PySide2 programming using QML. Just when it seems like I'm getting the hang of it all, including proper view/model separation and understanding QML concepts and binding, I've hit a roadblock.

I need to display table type data, so naturally I ran across the QML Table Model. But when I try to run a simple example that is pure QML from Python, I run across the error:

```
TableModelExample.qml:16 TableModel is not a type
```

The qml code is just the first example I found in [Qt's documentation for TableModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-tablemodel.html)

The python code is very simple:

```
import sys
import os
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # UI setup
    sys.argv += ['--style', 'fusion']
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "TableModelExample.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
      sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Can anyone explain what is going on? And also, are there any good learning tools for PySide2/QML when one gets to this point in the learning process?

EDIT:

Although the QML code was linked, here it is:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0

Window {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    TableView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        columnSpacing: 1
        rowSpacing: 1
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds

        model: TableModel {
            TableModelColumn { display: "checked" }
            TableModelColumn { display: "amount" }
            TableModelColumn { display: "fruitType" }
            TableModelColumn { display: "fruitName" }
            TableModelColumn { display: "fruitPrice" }

            // Each row is one type of fruit that can be ordered
            rows: [
                {
                    // Each property is one cell/column.
                    checked: false,
                    amount: 1,
                    fruitType: "Apple",
                    fruitName: "Granny Smith",
                    fruitPrice: 1.50
                },
                {
                    checked: true,
                    amount: 4,
                    fruitType: "Orange",
                    fruitName: "Navel",
                    fruitPrice: 2.50
                },
                {
                    checked: false,
                    amount: 1,
                    fruitType: "Banana",
                    fruitName: "Cavendish",
                    fruitPrice: 3.50
                }
            ]
        }
        delegate:  TextInput {
            text: model.display
            padding: 12
            selectByMouse: true

            onAccepted: model.display = text

            Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: "#efefef"
                z: -1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Pyside version:

```
pyside2                   5.13.2           py37ha8f7116_2    conda-forge
```

Comment: @eyllanesc See the edits for 1) and 2)

Answer (score 1):

The docs clearly states that [TableModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-tablemodel.html) was created in 5.14.

[image]

I have tested the MRE with pyside2 5.15.2 and it works correctly:

[image]

Comment: So QT version numbers exactly line up with pyside2 version numbers? It looks like the problem is that the latest Anaconda version (conda-forge) is not the latest pyside2 version. Learning - sorry for the incompetence.

Comment: @AndrewVoelkel 1) The version of PySide2 matches the version of Qt, 2) I don't recommend using anaconda as it has many bugs with Qt, PyQt5 and PySide2.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll create a fresh environment.